# Twilio Whatsapp API get customer name and display photo

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, whatsapi

how can I get customer name and display photo from the Twilio Whatsapp api

Comment: Hi! Can you share some of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From what I can tell from the [WhatsApp API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks#notifications), WhatsApp doesn't send the user's display photo as part of a message and you can't look it up for a contact.

They do send the profile name, however that is not exposed in the Twilio API for WhatsApp. The [request parameters that are set for WhatsApp messages are the same for SMS messages and you can see them all in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#request-parameters).

**Edit**

Twilio does now support [sending the profile name, and other WhatsApp specific properties, as part of the incoming webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters).

Comment: How this is beneficial to the business integrating to Twilio, if the name parameter is missing? As a business I need to be able  to see the name for better interaction with my existing or potential customer. I understand from a  software perspective that they have to reuse what is currently working to keep a uniform standard across but from a business perspective this is very poor.

Comment: As of this message, you do get the profile name as part of the message response https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters

Comment: That is correct, I’ll update my answer. Thanks!